# Prove that the union of any two $\epsilon$-neighborhoods is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $W$ be $\epsilon$ - neighborhood such that $W = (a, c)$ and $V$ be $\epsilon$- neighborhood such that $V = (b, d)$. So, $W \cup V = (a, d)$.

Let $n$ be a number in $\mathbb R$ such that $n = \frac {(a + d)}{2}$ and $ \epsilon > 0$ such that $n - \epsilon = a$ and $n + \epsilon = d$.

Then $\epsilon  = n – a$ and $\epsilon  = n – n$, so $n - a = d – n$ with $-a = d$.

Therefore, $J_{n - a}(\frac {a + b}{2}) = (a, d)$.

Am I close?

Thanks.

edit: $V$ and $W$ must overlap. Does that change anything?

Comment: I don't think this is true as stated. If an $\epsilon$-neighborhood is a set $\{ x : |x-a| < \epsilon\}$ for some $a$ and $\epsilon$, then consider $W = (0, 1)$ and $V = (1, 2)$. The union cannot be put into the form of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood. (That is, your claim $W\cup V = (a,d)$ is false in general.)

Comment: Is an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood a set of the form $\{x \ | \ |x- a| \lt \epsilon\}$ or a set which *contains* a set of the form $\{x \ | \ |x- a| \lt \epsilon\}$??

Comment: nayrb, can you elaborate why the union of $W$ and $V$ cannot be put into the form of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we war in $\mathbb{R}$: This is false in general, for the union of disjoint $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods is not connected,but every $\varepsilon$-neighborhood is.

Edit: With the additional assumption of $V\cap W\neq\emptyset$ your proof seems to be correct.

Comment: What if $W$ and $V$ are overlapping? I forgot to add that $V$ and $W$ must overlap.